# Echo the function's return value of a class or object in php?

Tags: php, echo

I'm beginning with PHP and I understand that in order to parse variables with an echo they must be enclosed between double quotation marks. But when I run this script:

```
echo "You have: Money::Add($coin1, $coin2)<br>"; //"Add" returns an integer
```

I get an error saying something like it can't convert the class Money to string. I know that it can be rewritten like this:

```
echo 'You have: ' . Money::Add($coin1, $coin2) . '<br>';
```

But when there are lots of return values, variables and so on involved to echo, I wonder if there is something I'm missing that could make the code cleaner and shorter.

Comment: nope. static properties, methods require you to break up the string, it'll work on instance methods though

Comment: can you put your add method code of Money class?

Comment: Maybe it works with heredoc?

Answer (score -1):

you need to modify like this

```
 $money = new Money; //create the object for class Money

 $result=$money->Add($coin1, $coin2) //call the function

 echo 'You have: ' .$result . '<br>';
```